# p:gmap onPointClick calling postconstruct conversationscoped

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, conversation-scope

I have a gmap as follows:

```
<p:gmap id="gOthermap" center="5.3096600, -4.0126600" zoom="13" draggable="true"
                type="ROADMAP" style="width:400px;height:200px"
                model="#{createCompanyReceptionnist.otherMapModel}"
                onPointClick="rco();handlePointClickOtherLocation(event);" 
                widgetVar="othermap">
            <f:param name="cid" value="#{createCompanyReceptionnist.conversationId}"/>
            <p:ajax event="markerDrag"
                    listener="#{createCompanyReceptionnist.onOtherMapMarkerDrag}"  />
        </p:gmap>
```

Each time i click on the map, the postconstruct method on my managedBean which is conversationScoped is called, how can i avoid that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check if the conversationId is propagated to the server if the event happens?

Comment: It is present on the URL, so i guess yes it is

Comment: Present on the url where? In the ajax http call one or in the browser url bar?

Comment: In the browser URL bar

Comment: Then please check the ajax calls with a browser developer tool